# golang: how to unload an already loaded "go plugin" 1.8

Tags: go, plugins

go1.8 onwards, go supports to create and load a plugin.

but unload plugin is not supported.

a plugin is a module loaded at runtime, is it possible to unload a module?

if not possible to unload a module, what is the best that can be done at application level to unload a plugin/make it unusable but still in memory?

Comment: sorry for the title, SO forced me to modify it multiple times because it didn't meet the quality standards

Comment: You can't "unload" a plugin. Can you somehow version your plugins, so you can load new ones each time?

Comment: why not add an Unload function to your plugin?

Comment: @AmmarBandukwala: what exactly would an unload function do, if it can't unload the plugin?

Comment: @JimB release resources. I assume the garbage collector will clear it's memory once out of scope

Comment: @AmmarBandukwala: that's not generally what "unloading" means. If you can free resources the memory of course will be garbage collected, but the plugin itself will remain in-process indefinitely.

Comment: I have been playing with this as well.  at the moment, it sems like you cant unload, and the best you can do is load a new plugin, perhaps with a an incremented filename - say the first plugin was `plug-1.so` then the next could be `plug-2.so`  in the end, both would be loaded, and consume some resources.  plug-1 might not be used, but it will still consume resources, unless the host process is restarted. if anyone knows a way around this, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Go doesn't support unloading a plugin. But you can, as you suggest, disable it. Commonly a plugin would define a struct containing the information about the plugin. You might return this from a factory function with a well-known name (e.g. `awesome.so` contains `AwesomePlugin`). One of the items you could include in the struct would be a method to disable access to the plugin. You could do something like this:

```
type MyPlugin struct {
    Name string
    Enable func() error
    Disable func() error
}
```

Then in the plugin itself you'd do something like this:

```
var (
    awesomeEnabled bool
)

func AwesomePlugin() *myplugin.MyPlugin {
    return &myplugin.MyPlugin{
        Name: "AwesomePlugin",
        Enable: func() error {
            println("Enabling AwesomePlugin")
            awesomeEnabled = true
            return nil // or do something more complex that could error
        },
        Disable: func() error {
            println("Disabling AwesomePlugin")
            awesomeEnabled = false
            return nil // or do something more complex that could error
        },
    }
}
```

Then the code to load it, enable it, and disable it would be something like:

```
awesomePlugin, err := plugin.Open("awesome.so")
if err != nil {
    panic("Can't load plugin: " + err.Error())
}

sym, err := awesomePlugin.Lookup("AwesomePlugin")
if err != nil {
    panic("Can't find symbol: " + err.Error())
}

awesomeFactory := sym.(func() *myplugin.MyPlugin)
awesome := awesomeFactory()

println("Loaded " + awesome.Name + " plugin")

err = awesome.Enable()
if err != nil {
    panic("Can't enable plugin: " + err.Error())
}

// Do some stuff

err = awesome.Disable()
if err != nil {
    panic("Can't enable plugin: " + err.Error())
}
```

You'd have the code in the plugin look to see if the plugin is enabled or not before running any other functions you might define.

Then, running it, we get output like:

```
Loaded AwesomePlugin plugin
Enabling AwesomePlugin
Disabling AwesomePlugin
```

Obviously you don't want to `panic()` everywhere. That's just a placeholder for doing something with the error.