# Golang plugin hot reload

Tags: linux, go, plugins, reload

i'm trying to reload a plugin in Golang, i'm using Go 1.8. I try to open again the plugin but that didn't work(Open opens a Go plugin. If a path has already been opened, then the existing *Plugin is returned. It is safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines. - Go Plugin open documentation). I want to know is any way to the reload without rerun the server?

https://golang.org/pkg/plugin/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [golang: how to unload an already loaded "go plugin" 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43375234/golang-how-to-unload-an-already-loaded-go-plugin-1-8).

Comment: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641296/load-package-dynamically-in-golang `exec.Command("go", "run", files…).Run()`

Comment: You may have to set it up as a full second program and communicate between the two with networking/something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, It's impossible since go can't unload shared library. When created some objects in the plugin, and it's referenced from program, it can't do garbage collect. See this issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11100